# Using nodejs as a webservice aside to website webserver

Tags: node.js, architecture

In my local computer, I have a programm that scrappes data from some website, periodically, once a day. The scrapping process transform the data from the html pages to a list of objects (This was developed in C#)

I want to upload the data to a database on a cloud hosting service (such as OpenShift.com)
Also I want to create a website that its server side will use the data from this cloud database.

The server side will be written in nodejs.

I will create a nodejs server for the website, that will expose an interface for the website to the server.

Should I create another nodejs webserver that will act as a webservice interface for the database operations?

My local scrapping program needs an interface to some server that will enable it to add the scrapped objects list.
The website need query operations on the data, but I want this query logic to run not directly from the database but from a middleware server.

So the question is more about good practice than technique. How would you design this architechture?